# How to save array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb, object

Hi so i have an array of objects that look like this

```
[{
             "id": 0,
             "name": "Del Vecchios | Italian Food | Asheville, NC",
             "domain": "delvecchiositalian.com",
             "email": "eat@delvecchiositalian.com",
             "phone": "828-258-7222",
            
       },
       {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "DeRango's Pizza Palace | Italian Restaurant | Racine, WI",
             "domain": "derangos.com",
             "email": "info@derangospizzapalace.com",
             "phone": "262-639-4112",
             
       },
       {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "Michigan's Premier Flooring Installation Services | D.E. McNabb",
             "domain": "demcnabb.com",
             "email": "no email",
             "phone": "(248) 587-1500",
             
       },
}]
```

And i want to store it in my mongo database but i dont know how to make the schema, my actual schema looks like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const infoSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        info: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 3200
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("ScrapedInfo", infoSchema);
```

and this is the controller for saving the data

```
router.post('/stored', (req, res) => {
        const info = new ScrapedInfo(req.body)
        info.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err+"error")
                }
                else{
                        console.log('saved')
                }
            });   
});
```

Dunno if i am making a mistake in the controller, seems fine to me, but i every time i run the button for the controller, i have the rror ValidationError: info Path `info` is required

Comment: can you do `console.log(req.body)`, what's the output.

Comment: Its an object that contains the array of objects that i showed first

Answer (score 2):

When trying to update an array of objects, using mongoose, you will have to tell MongoDB that there are pending changes by using the markModified(path) method. after this you will have to call the save() method.

example
We have the passwordsArr part of the schema as an array of objects.

// passwordsArr modified

// mark the path as having changes to write to the DB
user.markModified('passwordsArr');

// now saves the document user.save(function (err, user) { if (err) return next(err);

Answer (score 1):

Your schema should look something like this. The "Path info is required error" is caused by the fact that the key "info" doesn't exist in the Schema.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema
    
    // Schema
    const infoSchema = new Schema(
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            domain: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

// Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Info',infoSchema)
```

If you want to save an array your "info" key should look like this:

```
info: {
            type: Array,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 3200
        }
```

Where the "type" is Array instead of String.